# Angular 10 upload zip, get path

Tags: java, angular, micronaut

I would like to upload a zip file in Angular, and send the zip file to the backend (java/micronaut) and extract it there. There is already some implementation done, the backend receives the zip file eg. "File.zip", however it can't find the file

Is it necessary to add the complete Path of the file? if yes, how I can get it? from the Frontend or Backend?

Angular:

```
<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<input #fileUploadInput type="file" style="visibility: hidden" accept=".zip"
  (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)">
```

```
 uploadFile(files: FileList) {
    if (!files || files.length !== 1) {
      return;
    }
    this.orderService.importFile(this.order.id, files[0], this.appComponent, success => {
      if (success) {
        this.loadOrder(this.order.id);
      }
    });
  }
```

Backend (Micronaut) Controller

```
  @Post("/order/import/file/{orderId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public HttpResponse importOrderFile(
        CompletedFileUpload fileUpload,
        @Parameter(String orderId) {

    try {
        service.orderService.importOrder(orderId, fileUpload.getInputStream(), fileUpload.getFilename());

        return HttpResponse.ok();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return HttpResponse.badRequest("Bad input");
    }
}
```

Service

```
    public void importOrder(String orderId, InputStream in, String fileName) throws IOException {
    
            Set<String> extractedFiles = getUncompressedFiles(fileName);
    
            Iterator<String> itr = extractedFiles.iterator();
    
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                //...
            }
    
        }


    public Set<String> getUncompressedFiles(String fileZip) throws IOException {
    Set<String> files = new HashSet<>();
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileZip));
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    while (zipEntry != null) {
        String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();

        String fileName = zipEntryName.substring(zipEntryName.indexOf("order-nr"));
        files.add(fileName);
        zipIn.closeEntry();
        zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();

    return files;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Angular service code for uploading files?

Comment: the post request to the BE?

Comment: Yes!  the code used to interact with the back-end

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

You are making the assumption the file is on the filesystem and that its name is the name of the stored file.

Depending on your configuration, the file may only exist in memory. For cases when the file is stored on the file system, its name does not match what is returned from `fileUpload.getFilename()`. That method returns what the client reported the name of the file is.

Your `getUncompressedFiles(String fileZip)` method should instead pass the input stream of the file and it should be used instead of `new FileInputStream(fileZip)`